# Mysql Query : auto-increment manipulation and update on the foreign table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, foreign-keys, auto-increment

My tables are :

```
orders(orderID,orderDesc)
orderscoding(orderscodingID,orderID,codeA)
```

I have around 230 records for both tables.

I want to alter the (`orderID`) auto-increment from
1,2,3,4,5 .....   to 100001,10002,10003,10004,10005 
and reflect it on the related table , is this possible?

So basically this will not work, as it is for new insert (but I want to modify existing records):

```
ALTER TABLE orders AUTO_INCREMENT=100001;
```

Comment: "so basically this will not work, as it is for new insert" - what's wrong with new insert?

Comment: becasue i want to change the old ones

Comment: @TaReQMahMooD He wants to do it to existing rows

Comment: Yes its possible, but not with a simple database change command

Comment: can you explain please

Comment: Can we ask why you want to do this? Maybe that will give us an idea

Comment: yes i want to insert orderscoding into another table like orderscodingall (combine two tables) and because the other one has already autoincrement like 1,2,3 it will be messy

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if that's what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update existing `orderID`s, you can do like this

```
UPDATE orders SET orderID = orderID + 10000
```

All existing `orderID` will be incremented by 10000 with this query. So, 1 will become 10001, 2 will be 10002 and so on...

Do the same for `orderscoding` table to keep it synced with `orders` table (do the same if any more tables are synced to `orderID`.)

```
UPDATE orderscoding SET orderID = orderID + 10000
```

Comment: yes this will work but how can i reflect it on the other table and keep it synchronised

Comment: The same way, increment each orderID by 10000 in each related table.